# Failure while trying to resolve exception [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException]

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, one-to-many

I was trying to make a onetomany relation but am unable to add, actually it gets added to my psql database but throws this error in terminal and this on postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnsvg.png)

This is detailed error from console

```
Hibernate: select s1_0.student_id,a1_0.student_id,a1_0.address_id,a1_0.city,a1_0.locality,a1_0.state,s1_0.college,s1_0.name from student s1_0 left join address a1_0 on s1_0.student_id=a1_0.student_id where s1_0.student_id=?
Hibernate: select nextval('address_seq')
Hibernate: insert into student (college, name, student_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into address (city, locality, state, student_id, address_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into address (city, locality, state, student_id, address_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-03-16T19:02:08.786+05:30  WARN 8512 --- [nio-4209-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure while trying to resolve exception [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:447) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.sendServerError(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:595) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMessageNotWritable(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:562) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:234) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1341) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1152) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1098) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-03-16T19:02:08.802+05:30 ERROR 8512 --- [nio-4209-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.prependPath(JsonMappingException.java:455) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:792) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:733) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:733) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:733) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:733) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:733) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:733) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:2.14.2]
```

Here is my code for entities

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long addressId;
    private String locality;
    private String city;
    private String state;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "studentId")
    private Student student;

    public Address(long addressId, String locality, String city, String state,Student student) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
        this.locality = locality;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.student = student;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public Address(){

    }
    public long getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }

    public void setAddressId(long addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    public String getLocality() {
        return locality;
    }

    public void setLocality(String locality) {
        this.locality = locality;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Student{

    @Id
    private long studentId;
    private String name;
    private String college;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Address> address = new ArrayList<>();;

    public Student(long studentId, String name, String college, List<Address> address) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.name = name;
        this.college = college;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Student(){

    }

    public List<Address> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId() {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCollege() {
        return college;
    }

    public void setCollege(String college) {
        this.college = college;
    }

    public void setAddress(List<Address> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Service code

```
    public Student addStudent(Student student){
        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }
```

Controller

```
 @PostMapping("/add")
    public Student addStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
        return service.addStudent(student);
    }
```

I have been at it for over an hour and don't know what to do so I am here, I looked at some stackoverflow questions tried cascading changes, and made changes to the application.properties file, I was expecting the code to work I don't know what to write here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a circular reference Student refer to Address and Address refer to Student. It is failing while serializing the Student object to JSon. Try adding `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` to student field in Address entity.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "studentId")
@JsonIgnore
private Student student;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think that you need to make one of the relations Lazy otherwise you will create an infinite look when trying to serialize. Youre Entities are referencing each other circulary.

try smth. like this:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "studentId")
    private Student student;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work

Comment: you might need to annotate the service method with `@Transactional` so the lazy elements are not getting fetched by the hibernate proxy on serialization.

Comment: @Transactional is not working for me. But the problem is in this entity where I have the fetchType.Lazy... If I put @ JsonIgnore it works, but it seems a bit hacky solution!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the problem was the `@Data annotation`, I used only `@Getter` and `@Setter` in my entity and it worked fine.